# Automated line out switch

Tags: switches, audio

I'm thinking about audio for multiple props. Only one of 2-4 props needs audio at any one time, and in a predefined sequence. So I'm thinking have one source for the audio files, producing a line out audio signal (ideally stereo, might work with mono). Then have a low-cost (cjheap) device that, via digital command, switches the audio out to the appropriate prop. A single control input would be ideal, but I could make it work with a separate trigger input to switch each output.

So I'm looking for a device that takes one input (mono or stereo) and directs the output based on a command (from an Arduino, Raspberry Pi, or similar device). The sound quality doesn't have to be very good, so it doesn't really need to be audio quality. I know that automated relays exist, but they have separate inputs as well as outputs, and I think separate trigger pins for each relay.

Do such boards exist? If so, what are they called so I can investigate them? Thanks!

Comment: Relay boards exist. Arduinos exist. What exactly are you after? Put an arduino on relay board and make it receive commands and control the relays?

Comment: By "prop" do you mean "stage prop" (theatrical *prop*erty), or "propeller", or something else?  It's never safe to assume. :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with throwing computer connections at the problem. You can pass the information over audio itself. It's already there, after all.

Make a board with a couple LM567 tone decoders, to decode say 25kHz, 26kHz, 27kHz, etc. Enough frequencies to get the number of bits you need. The frequencies should be past the audible range, so they won't be heard.

Then use one of those bits as a latch signal for the rest of the bits. The latched bits can then control the CD4066 or 74HC4066 switches that route the audio to each of the props.

If the switching doesn't need to be super fast, e.g. one second of silence would be acceptable, then you only need three tones: one for serial data, another for serial clock, and another for latch. You'd use as many serial input, parallel output shift registers w/latches as needed to capture all the control bits.

The sound file for each of the prop groups would begin with tones that configure the switch, before the audible sound begins.

Of course decoding of the control tones can also be easily done in a single chip using most microcontrollers with a built-in A/D converter. So it doesn't need to be a legacy analog solution, and it'll still be very convenient. For MCU decoding, FSK modulation can be used and the bit stream would be synchronized by a couple of preamble bits, so only two frequencies would be necessary.

To generate the control signals, a little Python script using an audio library would do the job, for example. To make things easier to wrangle, the file names could contain information about which props they go to. For example, `tweets_03AB.wav` would be a *[bird] tweets* sound that should go to props number 0, 3, Ah=10, Bh=11. If there's more than 16 props - no problem, just continue with alphabet letters past F :) The script could scan a directory, read each file name, generate the control tones accordingly, then write the sound files with control tones prepended into another directory, with suitably changed names to avoid confusion, e.g. `tweets_03AB.wav` input would yield `tones_tweets_03AB.wav`.

A dozen or two destination control bits could probably fit in much less than 1 second while being reliably decodable - it was just a conservative upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother switching at all – cheap USB-Audio adapters are < 6€, so are hubs.

So, just buy a hub with four outputs, and four of these craptastic beasts (4,89€ each):

[image: Cheap USB audio dongle]

Attach four USB sound cards, [assign a unique name depending on which USB port they're connected to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675428/how-do-i-consistently-name-audio-devices), and configure your audio playback to use the right channel each.

Answer (score 1):

Here are DPDT relay modules with onboard driver transistors, so it can be driven by an Arduino output without a buffer.  Four of either of these will do what you want with no additional electronic components or circuits.

This one is continuous action:  the relay is pulled in as long as the input signal is high.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/173925061181?hash=item287ebdd23d:g:hK8AAOSwYd1c-N-E&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4Ixtw4ELaNt%2FT2OPEO%2F7IknfBL4TvdWceIYo8P7yejO5vAcZQf8pwzcJ1PqHbcuLUvzl1nTXsom%2ByVn4rpZkKcY8DEw4CWqloy6kKWQhZa6ZmGFmYhWq5vQEj8Hds14duTpZ4WUgcu2dyfJ2%2BdAxqOT7PYJb1v0p71pczj%2BxmN1eTCJKRcYJ7ggs0hJ2thZvZRMvDDZ1NWkXhOfqcmqIjkpnA3IrMWNfefbQNrlVkr7F3OavFm9rZECvj8DUVL9hlr2hOm2Z8VmZM2fDFcfgjD5PnLmImi4kmLBlQlmhcU9Q%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR8bMpcLsYQ

This one is alternate action.  Pull the T input low to activate the relay, return the T input high and the relay stays pulled in, pull the T input low a 2nd time to release the relay.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/392999424993?hash=item5b809753e1:g:CpUAAOSw8Ntfn7g6&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAwAoyrUsFeuBE30LoE3ZHKz50hTrjR7zPigDDmRo5Wxpd1WxcvIo06NvBkId6QA3p9e5Em4Uf%2BigEqADI9%2FYCS7hfHg0P685mUfc6xRwKR%2Fsb37okLkwsyE%2FIXyfjQ9Oo2QsIdrLBwO5UkJqxHXb0BxIR%2BDFsscuzxxuXs6MNO8WyQiazifXyqK9XCUBsd05eRwUn5ERVR1E9%2BIbQZ7He%2FeCj34ja76Y18kvr2byHQS6AeiGbvkx0A8zx1hlJ4%2Fwnxg%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR8jMpcLsYQ

Answer (score 0):

A single (mono) or double (stereo) four-throw rotary switch will do what you want with no other components of any kind.

So will a set of four pushbutton switches with a mechanical "bail".  This releases any pushed buttons when another button is pressed.  These used to be all over the surplus markets.

If it is inconvenient to route all of the audio lines to the switches, you can use a SP4T switch to control four small reed relays.  Again, very low cost in surplus.

If electronic control is important, then as mentioned there are tons of single and multiple relay modules on ebay.  Modules using electronic switching, such as an analog mux chip, are way less common.

Comment: Yes, electronic control is a key requirement.